# How can I change Assembly Version,Assembly File Version by compliling code using System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I dnt have Assembly Info file I have a code generator that copile the code using System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit, but always on compiling code Assembly File version and Assembly version remain 0.0.0.0

Any answer will really appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CodeCompileUnit unit = new CodeCompileUnit();`

`// ...`

`CodeTypeReference attr = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute));`

`CodeAttributeDeclaration decl = new CodeAttributeDeclaration(attr, new 
CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("1.0.2.42")));`

`unit.AssemblyCustomAttributes.Add(decl);`

should work with AssemblyFileVersion as well. [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/32394463-69d1-42b3-960d-f1577d0fbd51)