# C# / .NET - CodeDom.Compiler Set Assembly Info Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

I am new to C# and am trying to use .NET's CodeDom.Compiler to compile an application and properly generate the assembly information in the outputted exe. I've been looking in the MS Docs / Class reference to do so. Is it possible to set the assembly information during compilation?

Code to compile my source code:

```
CompilerParameters CParams = new CompilerParameters();
CParams.GenerateExecutable = true;
CParams.OutputAssembly = Output;

string options = "/optimize+ /platform:x86 /target:winexe /unsafe";
if (Icon != null)
    options += " /win32icon:\"" + Icon + "\"";

CParams.CompilerOptions = options;
CParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
CParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll");

Dictionary<string, string> ProviderOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ProviderOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");

CompilerResults Results = new CSharpCodeProvider(ProviderOptions).CompileAssemblyFromSource(CParams, source);
```

Outputted Exe's Assembly Information:

[image]

Is this function available when I'm actually saving the exe using the Writer?

```
Writer.WriteResource(FSave.FileName, EncryptedBytes);
```

I greatly appreciate any leads, thank you.

Comment: also duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989246/how-can-i-change-assembly-version-assembly-file-version-by-compliling-code-using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change Assembly Version,Assembly File Version by compliling code using System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989246/how-can-i-change-assembly-version-assembly-file-version-by-compliling-code-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead your last line

```
        ...
        var unit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        var attr = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(AssemblyVersionAttribute));
        var decl = new CodeAttributeDeclaration(attr, new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("1.0.2.42")));
        unit.AssemblyCustomAttributes.Add(decl);
        var prov = new CSharpCodeProvider(ProviderOptions);
        var assemblyInfo = new StringWriter();
        prov.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(unit, assemblyInfo, new CodeGeneratorOptions());

        var result = prov.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CParams, new[] {"public class p{public static void Main(){}}", assemblyInfo.ToString()});
```

generate assemblyinfo and add this to source for compilation

[msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32394463-69d1-42b3-960d-f1577d0fbd51/how-to-specify-assembly-version-when-using-codedom-to-compile-source-code-files?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.